# Smart mailbox for senders who are not members of a group

Tags: mail.app, contacts, smart-folders, mail-rules

I want to set up a smart mailbox in Mail that contains messages from any sender who is *not* a member of a particular group in my address book.

There's an option in the smart mailbox rules for "sender is member of group," but I don't see a way to negate it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maybe a bit counter intuitive but you can do it via the Contacts app.

You can make an intelligent group in your Contacts app with the criteria:

- is not member in group

and use this group for your smart mailbox.

Comment: Ha! So it's a smart mailbox in Mail for people who *are* members of the smart group in Contacts of people who are *not* members of another group. That's smart but totally non-obvious :)